# Want to keep upstream remote copy of git file

Tags: git

Forked and cloned original repository onto my own github remote and my own local machine. Also have a remote upstream pull system set to original source repository to pull in updated changes as well (this is an instructor's directory I have no push access)

I have a Jupyter notebook inside my forked repository and local machine that I want to make changes to, but I also want to pull down the filled out one from the instructor after he teaches (he is the original source repository). I attempted to change rename python notebook on my local so that it would pull down another original/his edited original and keep both my copy and the instructor's clean/filled in upstream notebook (which he fills in and pushes after he teaches). Doesn't seem to work with typical:

```
git push origin master (to sync my remote)
git pull upstream master (to sync the instructor's upstream remote)
```

Any ideas on how to pull this off?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just make another local branch and merge changes from pulled master?

Comment: Consider using branches. In git they’re _very_ useful.